# Standard Chatter:feed component returning a CORS error

Tags: visualforce-component, chatter, cors

We have a custom VisualForce page that consolidates a lot of information into one place. One of the components that we have is a standard Chatter:feed. Everything works great, unless we try to post a Chatter Question. The Question will post, but Chatter does not load similar Questions for the user to view. We thought this might be an issue with everything else on the page, so we created a simple VF page with this code to test:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="true">
    <div id="chatter-container">
        <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}" />
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Everything loads correctly, until I click on question and type in a question. That's when Chrome's Console blows up with:
[image: Chatter CORS Issue Screenshot]

To fix this, we've attempted to add the URLs from the errors in the CORS section of Salesforce along with Proxies and anything else I could find online. I'm to the point where I believe this is a Salesforce bug, but I could not find this issue listed. I'm guessing not many Orgs are using the Chatter Question in the standard Chatter:feed component and that is why this issue might not be listed. The other variable is we have a custom domain which might be causing some of this issue.

Does anyone have any other ideas that we could try to fix this?

Comment: Not that this is very helpful for you, but just as a point of reference that page works fine for me and I have a custom URL as well.

Comment: @caleb.breckon Did you attempt to use the Chatter Question option for your post and if so, did you view the console to see if there were any errors?

Comment: Yes, I used that specific feed item type and the question posted successfully with no errors on the console.

Comment: That is strange. Do you have answered questions available in your Org?

Comment: No, I made that in a pretty empty org. To clarify, the only steps I took were: as a sysadmin, created a visualforce page copy pasting exactly what you have above, open a new tab, navigate to /apex/test, and post a question. No switching Users, communities, sites, etc.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I'll try an empty Org as well and see what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a reported bug:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008dTvAAI